# Acceder a arreglo creando nombre en variable

Tags: javascript, array, variables

Estoy tratando acceder a los elementos de un arreglo creando el nombre del arreglo en una variable.

He agregado parte del código con el que estoy realizando el ejercicio

```js
function update() {
    let arr_2020=[73.04,2220.42,26645.04];
    let arr_2021=[75.49,2294.90,27538.80];
    let arr_2022=[80.60,2450.24,29402.88];

    var select = document.getElementById('sel_year');
    var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];

    document.getElementById('value').value = option.value;

    var arr = 'arr_' + document.getElementById('value').value 
    
    
    console.log(arr)
    console.log(arr[2])
    
    document.getElementById('value').value = arr;
}
update;
```

```html
<div>
    <select oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Selecciona una opción')" id="sel_year" onChange="update()">
<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Año</option>
<option value="2022">2022</option>
<option value="2021">2021</option>
<option value="2020">2020</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="value">
</div>
```

Comment: La variable `arr_n` que estás creando es de tipo `string` y no apunta a ningún arreglo. ¿Qué estás intentando hacer? ¿Puedes aclarar más tu escenario? Haz clic en [edit] y añade más información a tu pregunta. Considera añadir un [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: Lo que quiere hacer es usar un string que tiene como valor el nombre de una variable. Y usar dicho string para poder hacer operaciones a la variable que tiene el mismo nombre que el contenido de su string.

Comment: ¿Esto lo estás trabajando en el navegador? ¿En NodeJS? ¿Dentro de una función? Es que lo puedes hacer, pero dependerá de en qué ambiente te encuentres.

Comment: He agregado más código, lo estoy trabajando en Chrome, estoy intentando acceder al arreglo que corresponde al año seleccionado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es muy sencillo, pero has de cambiar un par de cosas en tu función. La declaración de las variables no las harás con `var`, `let` ni `const`, en cambio usarás el objeto `this` que apunta al contexto de la función, por lo cual las variables de los Arrays estarán "bindeadas" a tu función.

Para acceder de forma dinámica a la misma debes usar la notación de corchete:

```
this[nombre_dinamico]
```

donde `nombre_dinamico` es una cadena que coincide con el nombre de la variable que deseas usar.

Por ejemplo:

```js
function update() {
    this.arr_2020=[73.04,2220.42,26645.04];
    this.arr_2021=[75.49,2294.90,27538.80];
    this.arr_2022=[80.60,2450.24,29402.88];

    const select = document.getElementById('sel_year');
    const option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];

    document.getElementById('value').value = option.value;

    const arr = 'arr_' + document.getElementById('value').value;

    console.log(this[arr]);
    console.log(this[arr][2]);
   
    document.getElementById('value').value = this[arr];
}
update;
```

```html
<div>
    <select oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Selecciona una opción')" id="sel_year" onChange="update()">
<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Año</option>
<option value="2022">2022</option>
<option value="2021">2021</option>
<option value="2020">2020</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="value">
</div>
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Excelente!, muchas gracias por la explicación, ha funcionado

Comment: Gracias @padaleiana, ya acepté la respuesta